# In Mysql Workbench, where is Synchronize Model with Database

Tags: mysql, schema, synchronization, mysql-workbench

As displayed in Mysql [Database Synchronization](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-database-synchronization.html) documentation.

I cannot find this particular `Synchronize Model with Database` window / wizard under `Database ->`

I have Mysql Workbench 6.0.9.11421 build 1170 Community Edition

Comment: Yes, Workbench has a ridiculous UX.

Comment: Did you happen to fix it? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: @Frank, I just read your comment and again downloaded the latest MySQL Workbench software, still not able to find. I gave up on Workbench software long time ago.

However now I use HeidiSQL (opensource, free) for usual database task and for advance task like Database Synchronization I use another free software Toad MySQL http://www.toadworld.com/m/freeware/default.aspx?Redirected=true, it has the Database Compare and Schema Compare feature.

Comment: @AbhishekMadhani Thanks for your response. I've downloaded Toad (for OS X) but couldn't find the compare feature. Perhaps for Windows only?

Comment: @Frank, I am not very sure about it. Discussions on apple.stackexchange say that this feature might have been removed - http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/156991/visual-mysql-compare-tool-for-mac .

However not for your disappointment, try this script if it comes of any help - http://pastebin.com/Sbu9xnRL .

Comment: @AbhishekMadhani Well, apparently my IDE (PhpStorm) supports Database Comparing. I found out by the daily startup tip :P

Answer (score 6):

You must have a model open that you want to synchronize. Without an open model neither of the database actions (like forward engineering or synch) are possible.

**Update:**

Oh, I missed the exact menu item title. I was implicitely reading it as the existing ones. Well, sometimes items are renamed, so what you have in mind is now simply `Database -> Synchronize Model...`

[image]

Comment: I did have model open, still could not navigate to `Synchronize Model with Database`. Don't know if it requires some special user access or some other build of MySQL Workbench

Comment: In my Workbench 6.0 for Ubuntu, ever with the model open, this menu not exists.

Comment: I strongly recommend that you use the latest version of MySQL Workbench (which is 6.2.5 GA and 6.3. beta).

Comment: @TWilly do you have a model open?